# Конфликт импортированных css стилей

Tags: css

На одной странице использую несколько JS расширений (`DataTables` и `JqueryUI - Dialog`). И в хедере объявляю ссылки на их дефолтные стили `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=`. Появляется конфликт. Как указать для конкретного `div` стиль? Вот так не работает:

```
#dialog_create_product {
  @import url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css");
}
```

Comment: Даже если удастся подключить стили таким образом - все конклифты вы не устраните, т.к. в `jquery-ui.css` могут быть стили для, например, элементов в `body`, а вы запираете стили для них внутри `#dialog_create_product`. В итоге - они никогда не применятся к верстке jQueryUI-компонентов.

Comment: Таким образом подключить не удалось (. А как поступают в случаях конфликта стилей? В данном случае, как к конкретному селектору подвязать ссылку на css стиль, кажется что это должно решить проблему т.к. я думаю, что JS расширение использует только указанный `div`

Comment: Внешние библиотеки типа `jquery-ui` не нужно в принципе стремиться подключить в контексте какого-то блока. Это не модульные стили. Подключайте их как подключали, через `<link rel="...` и исправляйте конфликты перегрузкой кастомными стилями.

Comment: К тому же, возможно, вам не нужно подключать **тему** jquery-ui (`themes/ui-lightness`), а вместо этого - стилизовать интерфейс самому.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите ваши стили прямо в div. Лучшее решение - это создать отдельные стили для div - это повышает скорость загрузки. Возможно также редактировать стили jquery - я делал так.